# commandButton action method not executed

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

i'm working in a web application with jsf and primefaces.

My code for the navBar looks as follow:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="north"  >
                <h:form>
                    <img src="resources/images/logo.png" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <p:outputLabel value="Rechercher    " style="font-size: large"/>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <p:inputText  value="#{acount.searchWord}" required="true" requiredMessage="Le titre est requit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <p:commandButton value="Go" action="#{acount.rechercherLivre(acount.searchWord)}"  styleClass="btngo"  />
                    <h:link outcome="main.xhtml" value="Accueil"   style="margin-left: 400px;font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:link outcome="Contact.xhtml"  value="Contact" style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:link outcome="Info.xhtml" value="Info" style="font-size: medium"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:link outcome="Login.xhtml" value="Login" style="font-size: medium" rendered="#{!acount.connected}" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <h:link outcome="exe.xhtml" value="S'enregistrer" style="font-size: medium" rendered="#{!acount.connected}" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;

                    <p:menuButton value="Panier #{shopingCart.produits.size()}"   style="color: #045491;background: greenyellow;background-color: yellowgreen;font-size: medium">
                        <p:menuitem value="Afficher"    action="#{shopingCart.afficherPanier()}"/>
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org" />
                    </p:menuButton>
                    <p:menuButton value="Options"   rendered="#{acount.connected}" style="color: #045491;background: greenyellow;background-color: yellowgreen;font-size: medium">
                        <p:menuitem value="Compte"   />
                        <p:menuitem value="Mes Commandes "  />
                        <p:menuitem value="Se deconnecter" action="#{acount.doLogout()}"  />
                        <p:separator />
                        <p:menuitem value="Homepage" url="http://www.primefaces.org" />
                    </p:menuButton>
                </h:form>
            </p:layoutUnit>
```

And the image for this code is:

[image]

The problem is if i don't put anything in the imput text the action for the commandButton is not executed, also the action method in the menuButton are not executed if i don't put something in the inputText.

I can solve this problem with putting a form for each action method but my navbar got larger and it looks worth.

how can i solve this issues?

Comment: `required="true" requiredMessage="Le titre est requit"` isn't it pretty self explanatory?

Comment: Thank you ,I have not been paying attention because the message was never posted.

Comment: i have another question if you can help me , for the search function, i have just implented one like substring function , i want a function with more possibility for the search , because if the user forget one alphabet , there wil be no result . and it's bad

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to post any value to your bean by your commandButton then add process attribute to the commandButton. I think you are trying to leave some of the inputs blank and still send the request, but the problem is that one of them has the required attribute set to 'true'. Remove required attribute form your inputs and add process="@this" to your commandButton. I hope I am right.